# Command-line scripts in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I have some command line scripts that I would like to modify to use Laravel's features (Eloquent etc).

How do I do that? I am aware that Laravel bootstraps from the index.html file. Is there any provision for running command-line apps / scripts?

Comment: A good example for Laravel 9: https://www.positronx.io/laravel-create-custom-artisan-command-example-tutorial/

Answer (score 25, accepted):

1. Make a command using `php artisan make:command FancyCommand`.
2. In `/app/Console/Commands/FancyCommand.php` find a protected variable `$signature` and change it's value to your preferred signature:

   ```
   protected $signature = 'fancy:command';
   ```
3. Code in the `handle()` method will be executed:

   ```
   public function handle()
   {
       // Use Eloquent and other Laravel features...

       echo 'Hello world';
   }
   ```
4. Register your new command in the `/app/Console/Kernel.php` by adding your command's class name to `$commands` array.

   ```
   protected $commands = [
       // ...
       Commands\FancyCommand::class,
   ];
   ```
5. Run your new command: `php artisan fancy:command`.

Comment: Although this is actually the better way of doing it (compared to the closure based method that's being upvoted), you managed to make it seem more complicated that it actually is some how.

Comment: Thank you, very helpful! Also in Laravel7 you don't need to do step 4

Answer (score 10):

Yes, you can use Artisan commands:

```
Artisan::command('my:command', function () {
    // Here you can use Eloquent
    $user = User::find(1);

    // Or execute shell commands
    $output = shell_exec('./script.sh var1 var2');
});
```

Then run it using

```
user@ubuntu: php artisan my:command
```

Check the docs: https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/artisan

You can also use the scheduler: https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/scheduling

Comment: Thanks. I should've mentioned I'm actually using Lumen - does the above still apply?

Comment: Where does one put this command code? Looks like console.php is the place.